# Exporting DataGridView to Excel without Hidden Columns (With Column Headers) VB.NET USING MS ACCESS

Tags: vb.net

I want to export my datagridview to Excel without hidden columns. When I put the if statement to check for only visible columns, my output wont have columns headers. I also want the date format to be maintained

```
Private Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExportToExcel.Click
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim sheetIndex As Integer
            Dim Ex As Object
            Dim Wb As Object
            Dim Ws As Object
            Ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Wb = Ex.workbooks.add
            Dim col, row As Integer
            Dim rawData(dgvViewMode.Rows.Count, dgvViewMode.Columns.Count - 2) As Object

            For col = 0 To dgvViewMode.Columns.Count - 2
                If dgvViewMode.Columns(i).HeaderCell.Visible Then
                    rawData(0, col) = dgvViewMode.Columns(col).HeaderText.ToUpper
                End If

            Next

            For col = 0 To dgvViewMode.Columns.Count - 2
                For row = 0 To dgvViewMode.Rows.Count - 2
                    rawData(row + 1, col) = dgvViewMode.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value
                Next
            Next
            Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
            finalColLetter = ExcelColName(dgvViewMode.Columns.Count)
            sheetIndex += 1
            Ws = Wb.Worksheets(sheetIndex)
            Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dgvViewMode.Rows.Count + 1)
            Ws.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData
            Ws = Nothing
            Wb.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            Wb.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            Wb = Nothing
            ' Release the Application object
            Ex.Quit()
            Ex = Nothing
            ' Collect the unreferenced objects
            GC.Collect()
            MsgBox("Exported Successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict in Project Properties. Correct the errors that it points out. Edit your code in you question to reflect these changes.

Comment: Don't declare variables as Object unless absolutely necessary. Object doesn't have a Workbooks property, or a Worksheets property, or a Range, or SaveAs, or Close or Quit. See what I mean. You can't use the properties and methods of a specific type when you declare as Object.

Comment: `If dgvViewMode.Columns(i).HeaderCell.Visible Then` What is `i`?

Comment: `finalColLetter = ExcelColName(dgvViewMode.Columns.Count)` What is `ExcelColName`?

Comment: What is all this `Type.Missing` stuff? If a method requires these parameters, I don't think this is going to fly.

Comment: You don't have any worksheets in your workbook. How could you reference an index of one? Also, what is business sheetIndex? You don't need a variable. You could use the literal 1 because that is the value the only time it is used.

Answer (score 0):

If open to using a free third party library for .xlsx [SpreadSheetLight](https://spreadsheetlight.com/) makes this easy.

Full source in the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version1/SpreadSheetLightVb1).

NuGet packages

- For .NET Framework Install-Package SpreadsheetLight -Version 3.5.0
- For .NET Core Framework Install-Package SpreadsheetLight.Core -Version 3.4.0
- Load data into a DataTable, columns in the DataTable to not show set `ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden`
- Assign DataTable to the DataGridView

For exporting to Excel, Copy the DataTable and remove hidden columns

```
Dim dt = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim dtClone = dt.Copy()

Dim items = dtClone.Columns.OfType(Of DataColumn).
        Where(Function(column) column.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden).ToList()

For Each column As DataColumn In items
    dtClone.Columns.Remove(column)
Next
```

Then use a method such as this one to

- Create an instance of SLDocument from SpreadSheetLight
- Call ImportDataTable on SLDocument to import the DataTable
- If the header should be bold set as shown below
- If there are dates, create a style and apply to the Date column
- Optionally size columns
- Optionally rename the sheet

Sample code for import

```
Public Shared Sub SimpleExportRaw(pFileName As String, pSheetName As String, pDataTable As DataTable, pColumnHeaders As Boolean)

    Using doc As New SLDocument()

        doc.SelectWorksheet(pSheetName)

        doc.ImportDataTable(1, SLConvert.ToColumnIndex("A"), pDataTable, pColumnHeaders)

        SLConvert.ToColumnName(1)

        Dim style As New SLStyle With {.FormatCode = "MM/dd//yyyy"}

        ' Format modified date column
        doc.SetColumnStyle(9, style)

        style.Font.Bold = True
        doc.SetRowStyle(1, 1, style)

        Dim stats = doc.GetWorksheetStatistics()

        ' auto fit all columns
        doc.AutoFitColumn(1, stats.EndColumnIndex)

        ' original default name is Sheet1, let's change it to the name in pSheetName
        doc.RenameWorksheet(SLDocument.DefaultFirstSheetName, pSheetName)

        doc.SaveAs(pFileName)

    End Using

End Sub
```